# In Javascript, how can I check that DOM elements input has changed without hardcoding and comparing values?

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I have the following [StimulusJS](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/handbook/hello-stimulus) controller that aims to track certain `required` elements ([flatckpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) date selectors).

Once all those date pickers' dates have been selected, I have to enable the submit button in a form.

I'm having problems tracking that all the required inputs have been *inputed* by the user and since this should be a reutilizable controller, I can't hardcode a value and compare against it.

What would be an effective way to check that all `requiredTargets` have received input from the user?

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["required", "deactivable"];

  toggle(){
    this.deactivableTargets.toggleAttribute("disabled");
  }

  connect() {
    
    this.requiredTargets.forEach((element) => {

      element.addEventListener('input', (event) => {

        console.log(`${element} changed`);

        //if (this.requiredTargets.inputed?) {
          toggle();
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Would the `change` event work in your case? Basically in your example in `element.addEventListener`, simply update the `'input'` with `'change'`.

The `change` event will only fire if it detects a different value entered or supplied in an input element.

Comment: It does work indeed. But how do I check that all the elements in the requiredTargets array have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically inputs fields will have a `value` of an empty string ("") by default

You can use the JavaScript [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check that all required fields have been filled and are not equal to an empty string.

This will return `true` or `false`, and depending on what the case is, you can call the `toggle()` method

#### My Approach

On each [flatpickr HTML input](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#flatpickr--external-elements) element, connect a [Stimulus action](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/handbook/building-something-real#connecting-the-action) method that fires on `input` event.

Let's call it `handleInput` in this case, so our HTML should look like this

```html
<input
  data-<controller-name>-target="required"
  data-action="<controller-name>#handleInput"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Select Date.."
  data-input
>
<!-- replace <controller-name> with the actual stimulus controller name -->
```

Next, define the `handleInput` method in your controller like this

```js
handleInput() {
  const isRequiredFilled = this.requiredTargets.every(el => el.value !== '');

  if (isRequiredFilled) {
    this.toggle();
  }
}
```

NB: input element has a default input event so you don't have to handle that yourself. See the [documentation](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/handbook/building-something-real#common-events-have-a-shorthand-action-notation)

Comment: `this.requiredTargets.every(el => el.value !== '')` can be shortened to `this.requiredTargets.every(el => el.value)`.

Comment: Thanks, @connexo. I'm going for simplicity so they can follow along

Comment: Thanks @fortunee . I will be trying that out. I tried something similar at first but I kept getting an empty string back from this.requiredTarget.value . Might have been something wrong elsewhere, I can't recall. Thanks for the detailed explanation again.

Comment: @connexo Thanks! Could you briefly explain how the shortened version works? I don't understand what it is evaluating inside the block, if it's not compared to the empty string (default value).

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 an empty string is a `falsy` value, if `el.value` is not an empty string then it's truthy because it's now a string of characters. So if we just do `(el => el.value)` it should still work as expected. Does that make sense?